# Adding functions to a card game

Tags: java, function

Our school project contains on taking an already finished program from the Internet (for example a game) and to add some new functions to it. I decided to take the card game mau-mau from JGameGrid and I want to add following functions:

- When someone adds a card with the number "7" on the mid, the next player has to take 2 cards as a penalty. He can avoid this penalty when he lays down a second card with the number "7" on the mid so the following player has to take 4 cards as a penalty. And this goes until someone can't lay down a card 7. This person has to take the entire penalty.
- When someone adds a card with the number "8" on the mid, the next player has to pause for one round. He can avoid this penalty when he lays down a second card with the number "8". So he don't have to pause for but the following player has to. This goes until someone can't lay down a card 8. This person has to pause.
- When someone adds a card with the number "9" on the mid the direction is going to change. Everybody can change the direction if someone lays down a card 9.

I've been learing programming since two years, so Java is relatively new for me and I'm new here on Stack Overflow.So I need hints how to add the functions.

Here is the code:

```
// MauMau1.java
// For debugging see comments // Debug
import ch.aplu.jcardgame.*;
import ch.aplu.jgamegrid.*;
import java.util.*;
public class MauMau1 extends CardGame implements GGButtonListener
{
    public enum Suit
    {
        SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS
    }
    public enum Rank
    {
        ACE, KING, QUEEN, JACK, TEN, NINE, EIGHT, SEVEN
    }
    private final String version = "2.0";
    private final String info = "It's your move. "
            + "Hint: Double click on one of your cards or on the talon.";
    private final int nbPlayers = 4;
    private final int nbStartCards = 5;
    private final int handWidth = 300;
    private final Deck deck = new Deck(Suit.values(), Rank.values(), "cover");
    private final Location[] handLocations = {
            new Location(300, 525),
            new Location(75, 300),
            new Location(300, 75),
            new Location(525, 300)
    };
    private final Location talonLocation = new Location(250, 300);
    private final Location pileLocation = new Location(350, 300);
    private final Location textLocation = new Location(300, 400);
    private final int thinkingTime = 2000;
    private Hand[] hands;
    private Hand pile = new Hand(deck);  // Playing stack
    private Hand talon; // Stock
    private boolean isPartnerMoves = false;
    private GGButton okBtn = new GGButton("sprites/done30.gif", true);
    private Location btnLocation = new Location(480, 580);
    private Location hideLocation = new Location(-500, - 500);
    public MauMau1()
    {
        super(600, 600, 30);
        //    Card.noVerso = true;    // Debug
        setTitle("Mau-Mau (V" + version + ")");
        setStatusText("Initializing...");
        initHands();
        addActor(okBtn, hideLocation);
        okBtn.addButtonListener(this);
        while (true)
        {
            if (isPartnerMoves)
            {
                isPartnerMoves = false;
                for (int i = 1; i < nbPlayers; i++)
                {
                    setStatusText("Player " + i + " thinking...");
                    delay(thinkingTime);
                    if (!simulateMove(i))  // Error: no cards available talon
                        return;
                    if (checkOver(i))
                        return;
                    //          Deck.showHeapSize();  // Debug
                }
                setMyMove();
            }
            //      Deck.showHeapSize(); // Debug
            delay(100);
        }
    }
    private void initHands()
    {
        //    hands = deck.dealingOut(nbPlayers, nbStartCards, false);  // Debug
        hands = deck.dealingOut(nbPlayers, nbStartCards, true);
        talon = hands[nbPlayers];
        Card top = talon.getLast();
        talon.remove(top, true);
        pile.insert(top, true);
        hands[0].sort(Hand.SortType.SUITPRIORITY, true);
        RowLayout[] layouts = new RowLayout[nbPlayers];
        for (int i = 0; i < nbPlayers; i++)
        {
            layouts[i] = new RowLayout(handLocations[i], handWidth);
            layouts[i].setRotationAngle(90 * i);
            hands[i].setView(this, layouts[i]);
            hands[i].setTargetArea(new TargetArea(pileLocation));
            if (i == 0)
                layouts[i].setStepDelay(10);
            hands[i].draw();
        }
        layouts[0].setStepDelay(0);
        for (int i = 1; i <= nbPlayers; i++)
            hands[i].setVerso(true);
        talon.setView(this, new StackLayout(talonLocation));
        talon.draw();
        pile.setView(this, new StackLayout(pileLocation));
        pile.draw();
        hands[0].addCardListener(new CardAdapter()
        {
            public void leftDoubleClicked(Card card)
            {
                Card revealed = pile.getLast();
                if (card.getRank() == revealed.getRank()
                        || card.getSuit() == revealed.getSuit())
                {
                    setMouseTouchEnabled(false);
                    okBtn.setLocation(hideLocation);
                    card.transfer(pile, true);
                }
                else
                    setStatusText("Selected " + card + " forbidden.");
            }
            public void atTarget(Card card, Location targetLocation)
            {
                hands[0].draw();
                if (!checkOver(0))
                    setPartnerMoves();
            }
        });
        talon.addCardListener(new CardAdapter()
        {
            public void leftDoubleClicked(Card card)
            {
                setMouseTouchEnabled(false);
                card.setVerso(false);
                talon.setTargetArea(new TargetArea(handLocations[0]));
                card.transfer(hands[0], false);
                talon.draw();
            }
            public void atTarget(Card card, Location targetLocation)
            {
                if (targetLocation.equals(handLocations[0]))
                {
                    card.setVerso(false);
                    setStatusText("Card drawn: " + card);
                    hands[0].sort(Hand.SortType.SUITPRIORITY, true);
                    if (checkTalon())
                        waitOk();
                }
                for (int i = 1; i < nbPlayers; i++)
                {
                    if (targetLocation.equals(handLocations[i]))
                    {
                        card.setVerso(true);
                        hands[i].sort(Hand.SortType.SUITPRIORITY, true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        setMyMove();
    }
    private void setMouseTouchEnabled(boolean enable)
    {
        talon.setTouchEnabled(enable);
        hands[0].setTouchEnabled(enable);
    }
    private void setMyMove()
    {
        setMouseTouchEnabled(true);
        setStatusText(info);
    }
    private void waitOk()
    {
        setMouseTouchEnabled(true);
        setStatusText("Press 'Done' to continue or double click on one of your cards
                to move it to the pile");
                okBtn.setLocation(btnLocation);
    }
    private void setPartnerMoves()
    {
        isPartnerMoves = true;
        setStatusText("Wait other player's draw.");
    }
    private boolean simulateMove(int nbPlayer)
    // Returns false, if checkDrawingStack() fails
    {
        Card revealed = pile.getLast();
        // Get list of cards that are allowed
        ArrayList<Card> allowed = new ArrayList<Card>();
        for (Card card : hands[nbPlayer].getCardList())
            if (card.getRank() == revealed.getRank()
                    || card.getSuit() == revealed.getSuit())
                allowed.add(card);
        talon.setTargetArea(new TargetArea(handLocations[nbPlayer]));
        if (allowed.isEmpty())
        {
            Card top = talon.getLast();
            top.transfer(hands[nbPlayer], true);
            talon.draw();
            top.setVerso(true);
            return checkTalon();
        }
        Card selectedCard = allowed.get(0);   // Other strategy here
        selectedCard.setVerso(false);
        selectedCard.transfer(pile, true);
        hands[nbPlayer].sort(Hand.SortType.SUITPRIORITY, true);
        return true;
    }
    private boolean checkTalon()
    // Returns false, if check fails because there are no cards available
    {
        if (talon.isEmpty())  // Talon empty, need to shuffle
        {
            if (pile.getNumberOfCards() < 2)
            {
                setStatusText("Fatal error: No cards available for talon");
                doPause();
                setMouseEnabled(false);
                return false;
            }
            // Show info text
            Actor actor = new Actor("sprites/reshuffle.gif");
            addActor(actor, textLocation);
            // Move animated card cover from playing pile to talon
            CardCover cardCover = new CardCover(this, pileLocation, deck, 1, 0, false);
            cardCover.slideToTarget(talonLocation, 2, false, true); // On bottom
            // Save card on pile top and remove it
            Card topCard = pile.getLast();
            pile.remove(topCard, false);
            // Shuffle cards
            pile.shuffle(false);
            // Hide all pictures
            pile.setVerso(true);
            // Insert into talon
            for (Card card : pile.getCardList())
                talon.insert(card, false);
            // Cleanup playing pile
            pile.removeAll(false);
            // Insert saved card
            pile.insert(topCard, false);
            // Redraw piles
            pile.draw();
            talon.draw();
            // Remove info text
            delay(2000);
            actor.removeSelf();
        }
        return true;
    }
    private boolean checkOver(int nbPlayer) {
        if (hands[nbPlayer].isEmpty()){
            addActor(new Actor("sprites/gameover.gif"), textLocation);
            setStatusText("Game over. Winner is player: " + nbPlayer);
            setMouseEnabled(false);
            doPause();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void buttonPressed(GGButton button){ }
    public void buttonReleased(GGButton button){}
    public void buttonClicked(GGButton button) {
        okBtn.setLocation(hideLocation);
        setPartnerMoves();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MauMau1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In other words, that's a lot of code!

Comment: Exactly what Federico klez Culloca said. There is nothing fundamentally wrong with your question other than that you should maybe attempt your problem first before asking for help here but that's really too much code that anyone would dig through it for you. Find the part where you need to insert your code, try doing it on your own and if you get stuck while doing so, get back here and ask for guidance :)

Comment: Okay i will do that, sorry for that huge amount of code :´D Thx

Comment: Okay i tried it myself but i really just have no idea how to do it. Can someone please give me a hint?